# Light reaching 2 distant points on the earth surface

Tags: electromagnetism

I'm confused by this paragraph:

*In January 1901, in simple wooden huts, Marconi received a transmission from the Isle of Wight over 180 miles distant, thus proving that radio would work over the horizon;* something that many scientists thought impossible.

Extracted [from this page.](https://www.nationaltrust.org.uk/lizard-point/features/marconi-on-the-lizard)

How would light reach the antenna?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The radio waves were reflected from a layer in the atmosphere called the ionosphere.

Answer (score 0):

Well, to be swift, I suggest you read up about something called **Space Wave Propagation**.

The idea behind it is fairly simple. Since the Ionosphere is filled with charged particles or 'ions', it should essentially act like a 'conductor' and reflect the electromagnetic radiation incident on it. That *is* what happens in this case too.